# An Olympiad Geometry problem about finding ratios.

Tags: geometry, contest-math

In the figure there is a convex quadrilateral ABCD. The lines DA and CB intersect at K, the lines AB and DC intersect at L, the lines AC and KL intersect at G, the
lines DB and KL intersect at F. Prove that $\frac{KF}{FL} = \frac{KG}{GL}$ .

[image]

I feel like this question is screaming for menelaus but i can't figure out where; so i did what any desperate person would do in this case; write out all the menelaus for all of the collinear triples. But there were 10 triples so all I got was a page full of letters from which I couldn't figure out anything.

I would highly appreciate a synthetic solution using things like Menelaus, Ceva's, Area Lemma and just basic things (nothing too fancy like complex or bary)

Thanks!

Comment: This is standard projective result. Do you know cross ratio?

Comment: You offer no solution for us to check (hence your chosen tag: solution verification, is all wrong). Rather you want us to solve it for you.  That defeats the point of contest math.  Where did you encounter this question (text, contest, test, etc.), And can you solve it in any way, because I note you asking for an alternative solution?  An alternative solution to what?

Comment: @amWhy I am sorry for using the wrong tags; I will not repeat this mistake. I posted this question on MSE only after trying it for a long time when I couldn't solve it; I posted it on MSE to get a solution, so I don't think it 'defeats the purpose of contest math'. Also I thought the alternative solution tag was for asking about a solution using a specific concept only but now that I read the tag description; I realize my mistake. I am sorry.

Comment: @Aqua I have not yet learnt Projective geo; I will be looking to do that in the near future; thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you use Menelaus, you obtain $$\frac{LG \cdot KA \cdot DC}{GK \cdot AD \cdot CL} = 1,$$ where we ignore the signs of lengths.

Similarly, Ceva yields $$\frac{LF \cdot AK \cdot  DC}{FK \cdot AD \cdot CL} = 1.$$

It follows that $\frac{LG}{GK} = \frac{LF}{FK}.$

I ignored signed length out of my haste, but this is the general method of showing the result. As mentioned by Aqua, this used frequently in projective geometry, specifically because the four points form a harmonic bundle. I urge you to search that up, if you are interested :)

Comment: This was the perfect solution for my question;  So the main idea of this problem was to apply both Ceva and Menelaus to the right things. Now i get it. Thanks a ton. Also; I will be looking to learn projective geometry in the near future.